# Why when writing html file with PHP stalled at '&'?

Tags: php, html

I have an issue about writing HTML file with PHP.

I have this function :

```
function openHTML ($file) {
 if (file_exists($file)) {
 $handle = fopen($file, "r");
 $output = fread($handle, filesize($file));
  fclose($handle);
 return $output; // output file text
 }else{
 return "This file is not exists";
 }
}

function saveHTML ($file,$string) {
 $a = fopen($file, 'w');
 fputs($a,stripslashes($string));
 fclose($a);
 return "success";
}
```

When I'm using `openHTML` it's fine. But unfortunately, in file that I opened with `openHTML()` there are some `&`, and then I'm saving with `saveHTML()` but then string or codes that save stalled at char `&`.

Example : UPDATE !
I open blank `file.html` with `openHTML()` and I start to type some string bellow :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
This is my login page & user page
</body>
</html>
```

After I save with code `saveHTML()`:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
This is my login page
```

At last code to be missing. Stalled at `&`.

I have using `fputs`, `utf8_encode`, `fwrite`, `file_put_contents`. Still not solved.

Comment: In the first function you forget to call `fclose`.

Comment: @kuba Oke i tried, buat still not solved ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    $output = htmlentities($output);
```

on the string your going to save.

[check it out here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

It will change all HTML entities to their applicable charactors.
In this case your & will be changed to

```
    &amp;
```

Comment: And other HTML entities that *have* been written properly will be destroyed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you could easily check the charactor set first with mb_detect_encoding() but its a little overkill for this example.

Comment: Sure, but when it gets put in production and comes across other data everything will go pear-shaped.

Comment: sorry still not working. This i need for editing code HTML/php trough php.

Comment: @wpro I think you just need to change the format of the problematic charactors. I assume you've tried running htmlentities on your to be saved string? Does it continue to stall at the & even after you do so?

Answer (score 1):

Lone ampersands are invalid in a PCDATA section. Use `&amp;` instead.

Comment: The answer has an example. See the part in monospace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `fwrite()` instaed of `fputs()`

Comment: @Dmitriy Chekalyuk still not solve, i have tried fwrite,fputs,file_put_contents, and still not solved

Comment: @wpro Are you doing something with the string returned by openHTML() before the call to saveHTML()?

Comment: @Dmitriy Chekalyuk just I open file.html then output into Codepress, than i save it with ajax.

Comment: @wpro Do you mean that data you are writing to file comes from the browser?

Comment: @wpro If so, try to call saveHTML() right after openHTML() and look if error disappeared

Comment: @wpro Then the source of error may be somewhere in the client side. Could you show your client-side code?